# how to make an smooth glow effect for a clicked button for 0.5 seconds?

Tags: html, css

how to make an smooth glow effect for a clicked button for 0.5 seconds?
like on mobile version of this website:
https://yakitoriya.ru/menu-dostavki/yubileynoe-menyu
try to + - buttons

Comment: i was tryed .butt:active {
    background-color: #a2a220;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}

but 500ms dont works


LOL it works in mobile version

Comment: What about using Google, like https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.foo-button {
  /* Disable OS styling */
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  /* Rounded corners */
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* Text padding */
  padding: 6px 12px;
  /* Normal color */
  background: #2442a0;
  /* Text style */
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  /* Animation (“transition” timing) */
  transition: .5s background;
}


/* When mouse is above the button */

.foo-button:hover {
  background: #5b6bd1;
}


/* When pressed */

.foo-button:active {
  background: #6b7be1;
}
```

```html
<button class="foo-button">Button Text</button>
```